# Why does halohydrin formation occur?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am so confused with addition reactions.

My book just gives random reagents and say this that happens without giving reason.

For example, in halohydrin formation with $\ce{Br2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$, why does alkene attack $\ce{Br2}$ first instead of $\ce{H+}$ of $\ce{H2O}$ in an acid base attack. Isn’t an acid base attack generally quicker and requires less energy than attacking a $\ce{Br}$ atom?

Comment: Proton transfer would certainly be quicker if there was any incentive for it to happen. Sadly in this case there's zero incentive (arguably *negative* incentive), since alkenes are such poor bases and water is such a poor acid. Think about the position of equilibrium for such an acid-base proton transfer; do you think that any protonated alkene (i.e. a carbocation) is going to hang around for long?

Comment: oh okay. I was suspecting that? So is there like a way we can know how to rank double bond as bases among other non alkene molecules. Like is it stronger base or weaker than molecules with lone pairs or with certain atoms? Just curious.

Comment: You've been taught to compare the stability of the conjugate acid, perhaps? The conjugate acid of an alkene is a carbocation - octet deficient, positively charged, carbon - so don't expect an alkene to be significantly acidic, compared to something like $\ce{OH-}$, which has a happy, neutral, octet-satisfied $\ce{H2O}$ as its conjugate acid.

Answer (score 0):

According FMO approach, $\pi$ MO of alkene attacks $\sigma^*$(anti bonding) of $\ce{Br-Br}$. As a result three member cyclic halonium ion gets formed which is very strained. If alkene is unsymmetrical, water( acts as a nucleophile) will attack at that carbon which is lesser in hydrogen and ring gets opened up. Product will be $\ce{R-CH(OH)-CH2-Br}$.